# Am Using tinify in node js. Wow can we download supressed file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, github

I am using `npm install --save tinify` then uploading my image files using nodejs but I need compressed .zip file in my system .

When I'm uploading my image files through browser at https://tinypng.com after uploading it shows download option that is perfect. But how can we do same through nodejs?

Here is my code:

```
var tinify = require("tinify");
tinify.key = "myRightApiCode";
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("C:/Users/sourav/images/pgL_NA-10005_5.jpg", function(err, 
sourceData) {
if (err) throw err;
tinify.fromBuffer(sourceData).toBuffer(function(err, resultData) {
if (err) throw err;
// ...
console.log(resultData);
//need compressed file in my system
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tinify's method that converts and writes the compressed image at once:

```
var sourceFile = tinify.fromFile("uncompressed.jpg");
sourceFile.toFile("compressed.jpg");
```

Alternatively in your method try:

```
var tinify = require("tinify");
tinify.key = "myRightApiCode";
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("C:/Users/sourav/images/pgL_NA-10005_5.jpg", function(err, 
sourceData) {
    if (err) throw err;
    tinify.fromBuffer(sourceData).toBuffer(function(err, resultData) {
        if (err) throw err;

        fs.writeFile('C:/Users/sourav/images/optimized.jpg', resultData, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('It\'s saved!');
        });

    });
});
```

Hope this solves your query :)

Comment: sorry. I have less reputation. I can't.

Comment: The question is asked by you, so only you can accept it and it doesn't need any minimum reputation to accept the answers on the questions asked by you. You need to click on the grey tick under upvote/downvote options on my answer if it solved your problem.